# How to specify the good locale for number formatting

Tags: playframework

We have some big numbers the must be formatted using [grouping separators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html#getGroupingSeparator). Since we are a french company we want it to be a space. On our dev machines which have a french locale, everything is ok. When we deploy on a server which locale is english, we end up with comma separated numbers (1,250,345 instead of 1 250 345).

Is there a way to force the locale used by the JVM in play ? I tried application.langs=fr but this doesn't work.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

When you use the method JavaExtensions.format(Number, String) you can set a default language in your application.conf

```
# i18n
# ~~~~~
# Define locales used by your application.
# You can then place localized messages in conf/messages.{locale} files
application.langs=fr
```

This currently only works for language but not for language + country. See also [issue](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987-play-framework/tickets/924-fixes-for-internationalization-and-fallbacks-when-retrieving-messages). However, setting the language should be enough for your case.